# Equivalent of `pluck` that Returns a Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

In my Rails app, I've written a method that generates an array of unique names from a set of records in the database:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :author

  def self.all_authors
    self.uniq.pluck(:author)
  end
end
```

This method works as expected, but this application may end up having a large number of authors so now I want to paginate this query in the controller.

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authors = Book.all_authors.limit(10).offset(params[:page]*10)
  end
end
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because `pluck(:authors)` returns an array and not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Is there an alternative to `pluck` that would allow me to use Arel method call chains? Or perhaps a way to make pluck return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of an array?

Comment: looks like you want a uniq listing of all authors (who have a book). Seems like getting this from the Author and joining on Book may make more sense.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott according to the current code it looks like `Book` has a column called `authors` (not an association). Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: You're correct; the way thing are currently set up `author` is just a text column. That may change in the future but for now that's how things are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@authors = Book.limit(10).offset(params[:page]*10).all_authors
# => ["first pair of authors", "second pair of authors", ...]
```

You just need to call the `pluck` method at the end of the chain.

Otherwise you can use `select` which will only return the specified columns from the database:

```
@authors = Book.select(:author).limit(10).offset(params[:page]*10)
# => [#<Book author: "first pair of authors">, #<Book author: "second pair of authors">, ...]
```

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of both those solutions. The problem with the first  method is that all_authors is a class method, not a scope, so it has to be called at the start of the method call chain. I suppose I could make it a scope instead, but I'm not sure whether you can use non-arel methods like `pluck` in active record scopes. (Scopes are supposed to return `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects, right?)

Comment: And the problem with the second solution is that it makes `all_authors` return a collection of books instead of a collection of authors, which seems pretty odd to me.

Comment: According to this, my suspicions about using pluck in a scope are correct: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7223

I may end up having to go with select...

Comment: There is no problem placing a class method at the end of that chain. Just as you can chain `limit` and `offset`. Try it in your console. It only becomes a problem when you try to call it on an instance of that class.

Comment: Wait, really? Wow I guess that does work. I thought that since `offset` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that I wouldn't be able to call Book's class methods on that object but I guess that's not true. That's really neat. :+1: